# Error when trying to connect to Azure Eventhub: AzureTokenCredentials / IllegalArgumentException: name

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-eventhub, azure-authentication

I am following a tutorial on how to setup a connection to Azure EventHub in Spring Boot: [1]

When starting the spring boot app, I get the following error:

```
2021-01-07 13:37:25.447  WARN 16444 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext :
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name
'resourceManagerProvider' defined in class path resource
[com/microsoft/azure/spring/cloud/autoconfigure/context/AzureContextAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied
dependency expressed through method 'resourceManagerProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'azure'
defined in class path resource
[com/microsoft/azure/spring/cloud/autoconfigure/context/AzureContextAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied
dependency expressed through method 'azure' parameter 0; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'credentials'
defined in class path resource
[com/microsoft/azure/spring/cloud/autoconfigure/context/AzureContextAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean
instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate
[com.microsoft.azure.credentials.AzureTokenCredentials]: Factory method 'credentials' threw exception;
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
```

my.azureauth looks like analogous to the on in [1].

I am using Java 11. Here is the relevant part of my pom:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-eventhubs-stream-binder</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-servicebus-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Workaround. -->
        <!-- Apparently com.microsoft.azure:spring-cloud-azure-eventhubs-stream-binder:1.2.7 has a transitive -->
        <!-- dependency to the following package. However, it seems that the version is not pinned correctly, so -->
        <!-- we have to pin the version to a compatible one as a workaround. -->
        <!-- 7.5 is apparently the latest version in which com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.http.CommonContentTypes is available. -->
        <!-- For a similar (but different) issue see also https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/issues/650 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>7.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

Note the workaround regarding the dependency `com.nimbusds`.

I tried navigating to the relevant code. However, for some reason the code of `AzureContextAutoConfiguration.credentials`
is not available in the disassembled code of my IDE.

Is the version I used in the workaround in my `pom.xml` appropriate?
Does anyone have an idea what the error means and how to fix it?
Can anyone report, that this tutorial still works?

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-cloud-stream-binder-java-app-azure-event-hub

Comment: For anyone that might come across similar issues: I had a bunch of more issues with dependency conflicts, which I ended up resolving by not using both eventhub and servicebus dependencies in the same application. I tried for a while to resolve those issues, but after this split was easily possible for me I did not pursue this path further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here the root issue is

> "Failed to instantiate
> [com.microsoft.azure.credentials.AzureTokenCredentials]: Factory method 'credentials' threw exception;
> nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name"

I would suggest you to verify your `my.azureauth` and `application.properties` files again against the [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-cloud-stream-binder-java-app-azure-event-hub).

Also, as the [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-cloud-stream-binder-java-app-azure-event-hub) suggests, if you're using JDK version 9 or greater (you are using 11 here), add the following dependencies

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```